# How to add Multiple text Boxes in html Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Need Help
Click on Add Button make new Row of Text Boxes and on remove to remove boxes row in html and jquery 
here is html

```
<div class="select-box">
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button'value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"name="size" placeholder="Size"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"name="clr" placeholder="Color"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text"name="qty" placeholder="Quantity" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Here is the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brIyv.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. People usually come here with a specific question on a specific problem. Seems you have no problem currently. Show some code please. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like the below. The idea is to, on load, store a copy of the first row in a data attribute on the add button. Later, when you click the button, make a copy of that and add it to the container. Then just make the remove button drop the last row from the container when clicked.

```js
var row = $('#row-container .row:eq(0)').clone();
$('#addButton').data('row',row);
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  $('#row-container').append($(this).data('row').clone());
});
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
  $('#row-container .row').eq(  $('#row-container .row').length-1 ).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-box">
  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
</div>

<div id="row-container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size" placeholder="Size" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clr" placeholder="Color" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow,that was best answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Html**

```
<div class="text-right">
    <input type="button" class"btn btn-default" value='Add Button' id='addButton'/>
    <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size[]" placeholder="Size" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clr[]" placeholder="Color" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $container = $('.container');
var $row = $('.row');
var $add = $('#addButton');
var $remove = $('#removeButton');
var $focused;

$container.on('click', 'input', function () {
    $focused = $(this);
});

$add.on('click', function () {
    var $newRow = $row.clone().insertAfter('.row:last');
    $newRow.find('input').each(function () {
        this.value = '';
    });
});

$remove.on('click', function () {
    if (!$focused) {
        alert('Select a row to delete (click en input with it)');
        return;
    }

    var $currentRow = $focused.closest('.row');
    if ($currentRow.index() === 0) {
        // don't remove first row
        alert("You can't remove first row");
    } else {
        $currentRow.remove();
        $focused=null;
    }
});
```

**And jsfiddle (updated)**

https://jsfiddle.net/xjbks3he/2/

Comment: Additionally, if you enter text in the inputs then click the add button, the text is duplicated in the added element. Not likely desirable behavior. It might be better to store a copy of the row before any text is entered like on load. Or, at least clear the elements after adding the new row.

Comment: @DelightedD0D where did you find the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined`? Show me how do you get this error. And finely, the question is how how to duplicate rows, without any behaviours in inputs

Comment: @DelightedD0D ah yes, the code was fixed to remove errors. But we can't be sure what is behaviours should be with inputs.

Comment: @DelightedD0D fixed duplicating values

Comment: Word, you could further simplify your approach by using `$newRow.find('input').val('');` [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/xjbks3he/4/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes, agree

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, it’s quite easy to add or remove a textbox dynamically. The idea is quite simple, just combine the use of ‘counter‘ variable, jQuery createElement(), html() and remove() method. See below example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is `$(document.createElement('div')).attr...` better than `$("<div />", {id:"TextboxDiv"+ counter})` ?

Comment: Also, `appendTo()` on `newTextBoxDiv` will only append an empty `<div>` since you used `.after()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/hs0b7qzm/